# How we can check, which fragment is loaded from Back Stack in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

iam a beginner level android programmer.Now iam after an app development.And i am using fragments in my app.And while Loading a fragment iam hiding and showing some views.

For example ,there are 3 Fragments (Say A,B,C) and 3 views (say View1,View2,view3(these might be  imageviews)).
And while iam Loading Fragment A
         View1.setVisibility(true)
         View2.setVisibility(false)
         View1.setVisibility(false) 
and while iam loading Fragment B
          View1.setVisibility(false)
         View2.setVisibility(false)
         View1.setVisibility(true) 
Like this for Fragment C also.But the problem is these are added to backstack .When the back button is pressed ,ofcourse the correct fragment is loading but the views visibility is not restoring.

Can anyone help me please
Thank you